# Java understanding Base

Tags: java, string, boolean, radix

Hey so I got this question for HW, however a couple of reads and I'm still not understanding it fully. I don't understand what I am required to apply to receive the answer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        if (value.charAt(i) >= 0)   {
            if (value.charAt(i) <= base) {
                return false; 

            }
        }
    }
    return true;
    }
```

Comment: The question is very clear, you have to check if each character in the String `value` is a **number** greater or equal to `0` and less than `base`.. Where exactly are you stuck in doing this?

Comment: @Codebender Am I close to figuring it out? And I'm confused with the base's pretty much.  

`'public static boolean isValid(String value, int base) {
  for (int i = 0; i > value.length(); i++) {
   if (value.charAt(i) >= 0)   {
    if (value.charAt(i) < base)
     return true;
    }
   }
  return false; 
  }`'

Comment: Yes.. You are really close... Only a small problem... Your code will return true as soon as 1 character is proper... But instead you need to return false as soon as 1 character is **not** proper... So, negate your conditions and `return false` inside and `true` after the loop...

Comment: @Codebender it's almost there, I get a successful run on `assertTrue(NumberSystemService.isValid("0", base));` 
However a fail on `assertFalse(NumberSystemService.isValid("120", 2));`
What could be the problem??

Comment: edit the question and put your code... It would be easier to get help then..:)

Comment: @Codebender Noworries done, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditions are inverted.

It should be something like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        if (value.charAt(i) < '0')   {
              return false;
        }
        if (value.charAt(i) >= base + '0') {
                return false; 
        }
}
return true;
```

Or you can combine both the `if` conditions,

```
if (value.charAt(i) < '0' || value.charAt(i) >= base + '0') {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Still gives an failure, I put the Junit test in the question. Could that affect the solution?

Comment: @Alex, actually the condition in the `for` loop was wrong. Corrected it now.

Comment: Not working still, these are the pre-conditions aswell:

`Precondition: value contains at least one character
  * param value
  * param base (2 <= base <= 10)
  * return true if each character of value is between 0 and base-1`

Comment: Do you know what could possibly affect this from working so I can fix it up?

Comment: @Alex, got the problem... Actually when you do charAt(), it does a character (ascii value) comparision. So you need to change the right side to a char also. Check my edit.

Comment: You legend, it worked, I was trying to do something like that the entire time didn't know I had to edit the base value too. Thanks!